# Maps google-apps-script info using distances along a route/path

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out a way to show items using the map script with the following info:

10 miles north running along US 1 plot a marker 10 feet to the right(east) of US 1.  And to set for example that mile 0 starts at the intersection between US 1 and Main Street.

Perhaps someone has run into this before or something similar and will be kind enough to give me some pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Following Eric's tip I was able to create a function to grab a polyline for the road centerline from Google Maps.  Then use the google api service to convert that polyline into latitude and longitude coordinates.  From then on, it was all spherical geometry coding.  Below is my humble little code:

```
//Function to grab a centerline from the Map Api
//start = lat and long for beginning of roadway centerline ie [27.64681, -82.38438]
//end = lat and long for end of roadway centerline ie [27.71248, -82.33518]
//startmile = beginning milepost
function grabmap(start, end, startmile){

  startmile = parseFloat(startmile);

  var points = [];
  var plinex = [];
  var pliney = [];


  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setOrigin(start).setDestination(end).getDirections();
// Much of this code is based on the template referenced in
// http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/06/automatically-generate-maps-and.html
  for (var i in directions.routes) {
    for (var j in directions.routes[i].legs) {
      for (var k in directions.routes[i].legs[j].steps) {
// Parse out the current step in the directions
        var step = directions.routes[i].legs[j].steps[k];
// Call Maps.decodePolyline() to decode the polyline for
// this step into an array of latitudes and longitudes
        var path = Maps.decodePolyline(step.polyline.points);
        points = points.concat(path);
      }
    }
  }

  var lengthvector = (points.length / 2);
  for ( i = 0; i <= points.length; i++){
    if ( i % 2 == 0){
      plinex = plinex.concat(points[i]);
      pliney = pliney.concat(points[(i+1)]);
    }
  }
  var plineVector = new Array(plinex.length - 2);
    for ( i = 0; i <= plinex.length - 2; i++){
          plineVector[i] = new Array(2);
          plineVector[i][0] = plinex[i];
          plineVector[i][1] = pliney[i];
        }

return plineVector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Maps Service extensively, but it should be possible. You use the DiretionFinder to get the latitudes and longitudes of points along the path, and then do some math to get the offset for the marker.